# Datatable/Datarow If Exists Update Else Insert

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Trying to find an answer to this has proven difficult, since all the answers deal with SQL!

I have a Datatable `TestTable`. In this DataTable I have three columns, `ID`, `ValueX`, and `ValueY`. As I add new records to this datatable, I am trying to make an insert method that looks to see if the record exists, but cannot get a Select statement to use multiple fields. In my situation, I need to see if the Datatable contains a record that equals ID and ValueX, if it does, update. Otherwise, add the new record to the datatable.

```
public void Insert(string ID, string ValueX, string ValueY)
{
DataRow dr = TestTable.NewRow();
dr["ID"] = ID;
dr["ValueX"] = ValueX
dr["ValueY"] = ValueY;
TestTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? You want to do this in a single transaction? You don't know how to build SQL query? Or you want the update to happen in-memory?

Comment: I am trying to make the update happen inmemory, and am unsure how to write the query to check for the two fields.

Comment: I see you just accepted an answer. Please also consider upvoting it, to give more credit to the author. It's a common practice on StackOverflow to accept and upvote the answer you find most useful. You should be able to upvote after you gain 15 reputation (so you already have this permission).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Find` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6dh4x2h.aspx)

> **DataRowCollection.Find Method (Object[])**
>
> Gets the row that contains the specified primary key values.

to look for a specific `DataRow`. Note that your `DataTable` has to have a appropriate primary key.

**Example:**

```
// create Table with ID, ValueX, ValueY
var table1 = new DataTable();
var id = table1.Columns.Add("ID");
var x = table1.Columns.Add("ValueX");
var y = table1.Columns.Add("ValueY");

// set primary key constain so we can search for specific rows
table1.PrimaryKey = new[] {id, x};

// some sample data
table1.Rows.Add(new Object[] {1, 1, 100});
table1.Rows.Add(new Object[] {2, 2, 200});

// find the row with key {1, 1} and update it, if it exists
// else you would want to create a new row
var exisiting = table1.Rows.Find(new Object[] {1, 1});
if (exisiting != null)
    exisiting.ItemArray = new object[] {1, 1, 9999};
```